# Does Kafka Connect Sink with MySQL JDBC driver support setting isolation level?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, isolation-level

I tried to find setting about DB transaction isolation level in Kafka Connect docs - nothing. Tried to find such connection url parameter for MySQL driver - it seems it doesn't exist. Also I didn't find this setting for JDBC Sink in code on github.

Is it really only option to set non-default isolation level is to set it global on server side? But even in this case I'm afraid that Kafka Connect set its own default isolation level that I can't find how to change.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC Sink has a set of "dialects" for each driver and it looks like the `GenericDatabaseDialect` has a method called [setConnectionIsolationMode](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/GenericDatabaseDialect.java#L608), the `MySQLDialect` is not extending it, so that one must be the one used.
The config seems to be [`transaction.isolation.mode`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source/JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java#L355).
You could try to set that variable, you might need to [allow overrides](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration) too.

```
CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY=All
```

if you are using the Confluent's Docker.

Although I have to say that the code looks like the isolation mode is only for the JDBC Source.

Comment: Thanks for opinion!
And yes, I tried to investigate source code and saw the same - no evidence that isolation mode could be changed in sink adapters.